# Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server via Windows authentication in tableau prep?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, tableau-api, windows-authentication

I been trying to connect my AWS based windows 16 server to a Microsoft SQL Server which uses Windows authentication. All I received from the team was the server URL and the database name, I been trying to connect tableau prep to the SQL but all I am getting is the

> "SQL Server Network Interfaces: No credentials are available in the security package" error.

I have also enabled Windows authentication on the server but is it possible for me to manually add my Active directory username and password to the windows 16 windows authentication ? how do I approach this ?

Would appreciate any kind of input on this.